# How to convert/export SQLite database to Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access

I have SQLite database and it has many tables. I want to change the platform.

How can I move all tables and columns to a Microsoft Access database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.dump` command in the [SQLite command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to create a list of SQL commands for your database (use `.output` to redirect it to a file).

Then edit out any [SQLite-specific commands](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) so that Access understands them, and execute them one by one.

Comment: how can i referance my database file ? i put sqlite3.exe and mydb same folder.and command select , it could not find my table

Comment: ok ok i open it on windows command line with > cd sqlite.exe mydb